# Database security for code-first with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, security, stored-procedures

Wondering if there will be security issue with code-first and Entity Framework?

It will auto generate the three stored procedures for each table. For example, a table named `tblAttachment` will have auto generated stored procedures like this:

```
tblAttachment_Delete
tblAttachment_Insert
tblAttachment_Update
```

Application user is granted the permission to execute all three stored procedures and also `SELECT` all the tables.

If hacker got the credential of application user, basically he owns the whole databases since application user could do select / delete / update / insert the records. Should this be concerned? What is the best practice in here?

Comment: This problem isn't unique to EF code-first, you need to keep the SQL/Windows credentials secure regardless of which ORM you're using. Some pre-Entity Framework systems wouldn't even expose tables and views to the application's SQL/Windows login, access was regulated via stored procedures that required a session token which also enabled row-level security.

Comment: without EF, you do not need grant SELECT permission on application user account. You create Update/Delete/Insert based on the need and might not apply to every record in the tables.  It could be very hard to know what exactly SP will do based on the name.  But with atuo generated code, everything is transparent which bring the more security concern

Comment: I felt this concern is only to CODE FIRST.  or Code First will bring more security issue.  But I could not see any related paper for this